# Replace \N in Canvas LMS API calls to be NULL

Tags: api, canvas, data-files

I am extracting data from the Canvas API and the flat files that it creates have a \N in columns that do not have any data. I believe it is representing a NULL and I would like to know if the \N can be switched to a NULL during the GET phase of the API call.